# How to perform a segue directly from the first navigation controller in a storyboard in swift?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, swift2

I need to perform a segue when loading the storyboard from the navigation controller. Im using `UpdatesViewController().segueToPerform("SegueIdentifier.forcedUpgrade")` in the `viewDidLoad()` function but it doesn't trigger at all.

[image: Storyboard]

Comment: The generic instance created with `UpdatesViewController()` is not the instance designed in Interface Builder. You need the reference to the concrete controller.

Comment: Thanks @vadian. Im very new to swift. How do I do that?

Comment: It depends on the design. Actually the navigation controller is a wrapper for the subsequent view and table view controllers and the first controller is loaded and displayed instantly. I don't understand the design to have two connections from the navigation controller.

Comment: I basically need to show one of the two screens depending on a server call. Thats why I had it directly from the Navigation controller. Is there a more appropriate way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this by adding in another view controller and then sending the segues from there.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if the method you are using is correct.

how I load my other viewcontroller is by checking. For example, once the app loads, it checks if a user is logged in, if not it will push the `signin view controller`

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    //forexample using firebase
    FIRAuth.auth()?.addAuthStateDidChangeListener({ (auth, user) in
        if let user = user {


        } else {

            // assign storyboard to the name of your storyboard
            let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

            //instantiate whichever controller in the storyboard
            let signInViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("SignIn")

            //present viewcontroller
            self.presentViewController(signInViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)

        }
    })



}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Chris